# jquery show/hide makes image larger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a joomla template with a custom jquery menu. The width is 100% for all Elements, but when I hover with the mouse over the map, the overlay is slightly larger, and I don't know why. The problem is in Firefox and IE 11, but I think it's a bug in my code. 
I use Joomla 3.2 and Flexi Custom Code (version 1.3.1 - September 30th, 2012).

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
    <img src="templates/images/Banner_menu.png" width="896" height="410" usemap="#MyMap" alt="" id="main"/>
    <img src="templates/images/Banner_1.png" width="896" height="410" usemap="#MyMap" alt="" id="One"/>
    <img src="templates/images/Banner_2.png" width="896" height="410" usemap="#MyMap" alt="" id="Two"/>
    <img src="templates/images/Banner_3.png" width="896" height="410" usemap="#MyMap" alt="" id="Three"/>
    <map name="MyMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,283,430" href="/index.php/one" alt="#One" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="283,0,566,430" href="/index.php/two" alt="#Two" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="566,0,896,430" href="/index.php/three" alt="#Three"/>
    </map>
</BODY>
</HTML>

<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();    
$("#One").hide();
$("#Two").hide();
$("#Three").hide();
$("area").on({
mouseenter: function () {
$($(this).attr('alt')).show();
},
mouseleave: function () {
$("#One").hide();
$("#Two").hide();
$("#Three").hide();
},
click: function() {
window.open("/index.php/" + $(this).attr('link') ,"_self");
}
});
});
});
</script>

<style>
div {
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
img[usemap] {
border: none;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
}
#One {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
}
#Two {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
}
#Three {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
}
#main {
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0; 
width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution was to calculate the width reather than taking 100% width.

```
</script>
<style>
div {
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
img[usemap] {
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
#One {
position: absolute;
left: 5px;
top: 5px;
width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
#Two {
position: absolute;
left: 5px;
top: 5px;
width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
#Three {
position: absolute;
left: 5px;
top: 5px;
width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
#main {
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0; 
width:100%;
}
</style>
```